# Displaying data after choosing from a list

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to create a form which will allow to choose the employee id in a drop-down list. Once the choice is made at the moment of selection, other fields are automatically filled in by fetching information from the database.

```
<form method="post"action="">
    <select name="id_em">
    <?php     
        try
        {
            $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=gestion;charset=utf8','root','');    
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
            die('ERREUR : '.$e->getMessage());
        }
        $res = $bdd->query('select * from employe');

        while ($ligne=$res->fetch())
        {?>
            <option> <?php echo $ligne['id_em']; ?>  </option>
        <?php }
        $res->closeCursor();
    ?>

    <?php
        $requete = $bdd->prepare("select * from employe where id_em=?");
        $requete->execute(array($_POST["id_em"]));
        if(isset($_POST['id_em'])){
            while($res1 = $requete->fetch()){
            ?>
            <input type="text"name="nom_em" value="<?php echo $res1["nom_em"] ?>">
            <?php
            }
        }
        $requete->closecursor();
    ?>
    </select> 
</form>
```

The drop-down list appears well, but when I make a choice nothing happens. I know we will use JavaScript but the problem is that I am still a beginner and I don't know how to do.

Comment: `<option value="<?php echo $ligne['id_em']; ?>"><?php echo $ligne['id_em']; ?></option>`

Comment: You should restructure this code. You build your form and select regardless of if the DB selects. You also do nothing with the `select * from employe where id_em=?`. PHP executes first, maybe you want to use ajax and populate the page without reloading?

Comment: If you want to execute an action when the value of the select changes, take a look at the onchange event: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp

Comment: @Spectarion The value attribute of the option tag is optional - see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option)

Comment: Man, you really should figure out where the period and the comma are located on your keyboard. Please see how I updated your question.

Answer (score 0):

At minimum you should call a JavaScript function when the selection of your list changes:

```js
function changeId(sel) {
   alert('id changed to '+sel.value);
}
```

```html
Options
<select name="id_em" onchange="changeId(this)">
    <option>(none)</option>
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
    <option>Option 3</option>
    <option>Option 4</option>
</select>
```

For further hints especially on how to use AJAX techniques to load content from the database into a html page see some of the excellent tutorials in the web, like this one: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp

Comment: No I would like when I select An item in drop-down list Show me the results That I retrieve from database in text field

Comment: I said I would like when I choose an item in the list it displays the result in text field

Comment: @Igoussam I update my answer and insert a hint where to find further information. Please keep in mind that StackOverflow is not a code writing service.